# Optimality like proof for hilbert Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Hi guys I am showing the following claim:

For $K = k + L \subset H$ where $H$ is a Hilbert space, $L$ is a linear subspace, and $k$ is some element of $H$. Then for a differential function $g: K \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and to the problem 
$$min_{x \in K} f(x)$$

Then the local min (solution) $x^{min}$ needs to satisfy $\nabla g(x^{min}) \in L^\perp $

My work so far: By definition of min we have that 
 $g(x^{min}) <= g( x^{min}+t(x-x^{min}))$

For $t>0$ and $t \rightarrow 0$

I think that even for Banach spaces we still have Taylor expansions so we may write
$g( x^{min}+t(x-x^{min})) = g(x^{min}) + t \langle \nabla g (x^{min} ), x- x^{min}\rangle + o (t^2)$

Where $\nabla g$ is the Frechet derivative. Putting the two expressions together we get 
$$0 \leq t \langle \nabla g (x^{min} ), x- x^{min}\rangle + o (t^2)$$

If we divide by $t$ and take the limit as $t \rightarrow 0$ we obtain
$$ 0 \leq t \langle \nabla g (x^{min}, x- x^{min}\rangle$$ I think now we can repeat the argument for $t < 0 $ and we will get that $\langle \nabla g (x^{min} ),x- x^{min}\rangle = 0$. Now because every point in $L$ can be represented as $\overline x- x$ for some $\overline x \in K$ this shows my claim.

I would appreciate if people can let me know if this seems legit and acceptable proof or if there are any issues.( I am most worried if this taylor expansion idea is true, I think we can do taylor expansions for Banach spaces and Hilbert spaces are such, but I have no experience in such matters)

Thank you

Comment: Hi Kori, you may want to define your notation (what are $L$ and $K$ and $\nabla g$). Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is almost correct. In the Taylor expansion, you should have $o(h)$ instead of $o(h^2)$. Then, this Taylor expansion is just the definition of the Fréchet derivative.